# How to execute php query(using if condition) based on select option?

Tags: php, wordpress, select

How to execute php query(using if condition) based on select option?

My select query is

```
<select>
<option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose Price</option>
<option value="1">Under 50000</option>
<option value="2">50000 to 100000</option>
<option value="3">100000 to 150000</option>
</select>
```

And here is my php code

```
<?php 
$my_query = new WP_query();
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array('posts_per_page'=> 6,'post_type'=> 'page', 'paged' => $paged, 'order'=> 'DESC',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
    'key'=> 'wpcf-just-launched-bikes',
    'value'     => '1',
    ),
),
);
$my_query->query($args);
if ($my_query->have_posts()) : while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
?>
```

If i select first option(Under 50000) then execute above php code
If i have select second option i want to execute another php code likewise

**(Note: better use if condition)**

Answer (score 0):

do you passing price (select) value in query page??
if yes :

```
<?php
$price = pricevalue; / store select value here
$my_query = new WP_query();
if($price == 2){
    // query or your code
}elseif($price == 3){
    // query or your code
}else{
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array('posts_per_page'=> 6,'post_type'=> 'page', 'paged' => $paged, 'order'=> 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
    array(
    'key'=> 'wpcf-just-launched-bikes',
    'value'     => '1',
    ),
    ),
);
}
$my_query->query($args);
if ($my_query->have_posts()) : while ($my_query->have_posts()) :
$my_query->the_post();

// after endif  
wp_reset_postdata(); // add this code
?>
```

Comment: How to pass my select value to if condition @Preet